# Find inverse composition

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

I've been stuck for an hour trying to solve this composition function:

If $f(\sqrt[7] x)=g(3x-5)$, then $[(g^{-1}\circ f)^{-1} \circ g^{-1}](x)=\ldots$

My friend gave me a hint that I should find $f^{-1}$ first, but I don't really get it. Can someone help me to understand this problem?

Comment: I think the hint of your friend comes from: $(g^{-1}\circ f)^{-1}\circ g^{-1}=(f^{-1}\circ g)\circ g^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ(g\circ g^{-1})=f^{-1}$. But I don't see a way to find $f^{-1}$.

Comment: i was thinking the same way

Comment: im stuck at $f(\sqrt[7] {\frac {y+5}3}$ when i tried to let *y=3x-5* but im not sure

Comment: Is this a functional equation?
It is not clear to me what is demanded.

Comment: just tryiinf to find $f^{-1}$ but i dont know how

Comment: A hint could maybe be: $(f \circ g)^{-1} = g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$

Comment: @Shuri2060: it is more complicated and probably harder to digest than what I wrote.

Comment: More to read and make sense of increases the risk of mental block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given $f(x^{\frac{1}{7}})=g(3x-5)$ and asked to find ${(g^{-1}\circ f)}^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$.

Since you've been asked to find this, you can assume $g$ and $(g^{-1}\circ f)$ are invertible. Therefore $g \circ(g^{-1}\circ f)=f$ is invertible.

Now,

$$f(x^{\frac{1}{7}})=g(3x-5)\iff f(x)=g(3x^7-5)\iff f^{-1}(x)={\left(\frac{g^{-1}(x)+5}{3}\right)}^{1\over7}$$

These are equivalent statements, so you've essentially been given the last statement, and asked to find ${(g^{-1}\circ f)}^{-1}\circ g^{-1}=(f^{-1}\circ g)\circ g^{-1}=f^{-1}$.

Therefore you can choose any invertible $g(x)$, and this is as far as you can get.